# how to exclude path information in gradle zip task

Tags: gradle, zip, build.gradle

Apologies in advance for this simple question I am relatively new to Gradle.

I would like to run a `Zip` task during my Build process and create a `.zip` file in my "archive" directory but without the source file's directory structure. I managed to get the `task` working but its retaining the directory structure. I read that for linux Zip there is the option -j or -r which flattens the directory but I am not sure if this is available to me via the Gradle task.

```
My input file structures looks similar to the below,
    ./libs/
    ./libs/file1.jar
    ./scripts/script1.sh
    ./scripts/script2.sh
```

but I would like to end up with a Zip file with directory structure as follows,

```
./
./file1.jar
./script1.sh
./script2.sh
```

My current Zip task is as follows,

```
task makeZipForDeploy(type: Zip) {
            from 'build/'
            include 'libs/*' //to include all files in libs folder
            include 'scripts/*' //to include all files in the scripts folder
            archiveName("${archiveFileName}")
            destinationDir file("${archivePath}")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was even more trivial than I thought. The below will flatten the structure

> ```
> task makeZipForDeploy(type: Zip) {
>     from 'build/libs' //to include all files in libs folder
>     from 'build/scripts' //to include all files in the scripts folder
>     archiveName("${archiveFileName}")
>     destinationDir file("${archivePath}")
> }
> ```